# Redshift - Using output from a nested query as input to another query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, subquery

I have a nested query that goes like

```
with q1 as (select * from table1), 
q2 as (select * from table2) 
select q1.col1, q2.col2,listagg(q1.id || ' - ' || q2.id, ', ') as unique_id  
from q1 join q2 on q1.id = q2.id;
```

I am trying to use **unique_id** obtained from the above query and query another table.

Could anyone guide me how could I use this new column created in the above query used as an input to another query. Thanks

I am using Redshift DB. Thanks

Comment: Your query is not valid.  You are using an aggregation function with no `group by`.

Comment: Put that select into q3.

Comment: There is a lot here that doesn't make sense to me.  I think you need to flesh things out in to a more concrete example, so that we can see what you're working with and what you're trying to achieve *(using example input data and corresponding desired results)*.  Perhaps, read this link too?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following :

```
create table table1(id int,col1 varchar(10));
create table table2(id int,col2 varchar(10));

insert into table1 values(1,'A');
insert into table1 values(2,'B');
insert into table2 values(1,'C');
insert into table2 values(2,'D');

with q(col1, col2, id1, id2) as
 (
  select q1.col1, q2.col2, q1.id as id1, q2.id as id2
  from table1 q1
  join table2 q2
    on q1.id = q2.id 
 )
select col1,col2,
       listagg(id1 || ' - ' || id2, ', ') within group ( order by id1 ) as unique_id
  from q
 group by col1,col2;

COL1    COL2    UNIQUE_ID
  A       C       1 - 1
  B       D       2 - 2
```

you need to add `group by` as @Gordon pointed out, and `listagg` function cannot be used lonely. So `within group ( order by ..` clause is added.